# Why HorizontalScrollView not scroll in HTCDesire 2.2 but only on simulator?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am using a `HorizentalScrollView` in a view. I add `TextView` at runtime. I use `horView.smoothScrollTo(x,y)`;   It works fine for simulator. But it doesn't scroll at HTCDesire 2.2 ? any idea? here my code.

```
horView.smoothScrollTo(num, 0);


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/cate_head"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:background="@drawable/slider_background"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cate_head_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found solution. I was calling smoothScrollTo(x,y) at the end of on create.(where else I can put that?) problem was that at the time of initializing there was not size or length found(But it should not be, because I have put all the data in that).
So call postDealy() with a delay of 50 sec. It works for me. Here is that. I put it at the end of onCreate(); 
May b anyone else have a batter solution...

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            horView.smoothScrollTo((scrollAmount), 0);
        }
    }, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use View.post to avoid depending on timing.

```
horView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        horView.smoothScrollTo((scrollAmount), 0);          
    }
});
```

This gets executed right after the view has been attached to the screen.